# Spring transactions for checked exceptions

Tags: spring-data, spring-transactions

I'm struggling with a method in a Spring Service component which should be transactional. The method calls two other methods defined in the same class, both of them persisting data using Spring repositories extending `JpaRepository` (and therefore may throw unchecked exceptions), but one method (`methodB`) is also doing some filesystem operations which may throw checked exceptions. What is the correct to make this method transactional? So far I have this:

```
    @Service
    public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
      @Transactional
      public void doStuff() {
        methodA();
        try {  
          methodB();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
          throw new RuntimeException();
        }
      }

      public void methodB() throws MyCheckedExcpetion() {
        // some stuff
      }
      public void methodA() {
        // some stuff
      }
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can't you do `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` or `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)` and get rid of the `try...catch` block?

Comment: I think I could, but wasn't quite sure whether I have to throw the MyCheckedExcpetion from the doStuff() method, or handle it within the method.

Comment: Yes, `doStuff` will have to throw `Exception` so that the interceptor for `@Transactional` catches it.  The way you have structured the code right now is also fine since you are rethrowing a checked exception as a runtime exception that will be caught by the interceptor for `@Transactional`.